# Targeting an iframe with Js/jQuery BEFORE the DOM loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, servicenow

In order to prevent an iframe from flashing, I'm setting its visibility inside a setTimeout (the CSS is set to visibility:hidden)

```
setTimeout(function(){  
$n('#myFrame').css('visibility','visible');}, 750);
```

Works great, although when I load subsequent locations inside the frame, the flashing behavior returns since the visibility is already set.

What I'd like to do is create a function that targets the iframe BEFORE the DOM/page has loaded to set the visibility to hidden again and then setTimeout.

Keep in mind that this script will run on the ServiceNow platform, meaning some options are limited (can't load in document head, etc.)

It's sort of like a reverse document.ready(). Is this even possible?

Thanks for any leads,

Paco

Comment: javascript needs an event to run. figure out what event causes the iframe to change and have said event hide it and reshow it again as needed.

Comment: Hi Paco, Have you found a solution for this? I'm stuck, trying to hide everything in an UI Page using Jelly, and it seems that it will always be fired after Dom load complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set it in your source:

```
<iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Then un-hide it when you want to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('buttonToChangeTheIframePage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

      $('#myFrame').css('visibility','hidden'); 
      $('#myFrame').delay(1000).css('visibility','visible');
});
```

This assumes you are loading locations from OUTSIDE the iframe - anything within the iframe (like a link) will still trigger this behaviour.

**EDIT**

This is actually better and will work for all circumstances (I think - just check no silly errors as not tested)

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.google.com/" onLoad="hideUnhide();"></iframe>

function hideUnhide(){
    $('#myFrame').css('visibility','hidden').delay(1000).css('visibility','visible');

}
```

Comment: I'm indeed loading locations from inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addAfterPageLoadedEvent(func)` in `js_include_doc_type.js`

```
<iframe id="gsft_main" style="visibility: hidden;">

anything ....

<script>
 addAfterPageLoadedEvent(function() {
    $j('#gsft_main').css('visibility','visible');
 });
</script>

</iframe>
```